# Недоступность функции в JS из файла

Tags: javascript, функции

Функция tcategories недоступна из js файла. В чём проблема?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function tcategories() {
    alert(1);
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**all.js:**

```
setTimeout(function() {tcategories()}, 3000);
```

**Консоль:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tcategories
> is not defined

Comment: Очень странно. Скопировал Ваш код - всё отработало как должно.
Может проблема с правами файлов?

Comment: Вы вызываете функцию в файле, подключенном в шапке, но саму функцию огласили в теле документа.
Либо перенесите tcategories() в all.js, либо подключите all.js после обьявления функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, во первых нет гарантии что код из all.js выполняется после того как загрузился скрипт из DOM. Повестись не на таймаут, а на document.ready. Так же в all.js можете определить `var functions = {}` и в скрипте присвоить значение `functions.tcategories = function ()...;`